# Can I move the debugger context up and down the stack?

Tags: perl, debugging

Basically I'm looking for the perl equivalent of gdb's "up" and "down" commands.  If I break on subroutine `bar`, and I have a call stack that looks like this:

```
foo
  \
   baz
    \
     bar
```

I'd like to be able to (without returning from `bar` or `baz`) navigate up the `foo` frame and see what it was doing by manipulating variables as I ordinarily would using arguments to `p` or `x`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`y` command](http://p3rl.org/debug#y-%5blevel-%5bvars%5d%5d).

```
$ cat frames.pl
sub bar {
    my $fnord = 42;
    1
}
sub baz { bar }
sub foo {
    my $fnord = 23;
    baz
};
foo;
$ perl -d frames.pl

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.37
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(frames.pl:10):   foo;
DB<1> c 3
main::bar(frames.pl:3):     1
DB<2> y 2 fnord
$fnord = 23
DB<3> T
. = main::bar() called from file 'frames.pl' line 5
. = main::baz() called from file 'frames.pl' line 8
. = main::foo() called from file 'frames.pl' line 10
```

Comment: Neat indeed, +1, however this still seems to offer less than gdb does - setting the values of lexical variables in other frames, evaluating expressions containing lexical variables, etc.  I'm still wondering if that's possible in the perl debugger...

Comment: You can construct expressions that are more powerful than `y varname` with the help of [PadWalker](http://p3rl.org/PadWalker) or [Devel::LexAlias](http://p3rl.org/Devel::LexAlias), perhaps write a debugger macro to abstract away the unwieldy syntax if you need it often. I can't imagine why you'd want to change a lexical variable that's not ordinarily accessible from the scope you're in; they by design have no effect at a distance.